# AmazonCognitoIdentity AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am developing an app and I need use Amazon Cognito for access to AS3 services.

I created an IdentityPool and I have my IdentityPoolId and I created my Developer provider so, I have my Developer provider name. But when I execute `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity`, the response is null:

> (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;

```
    try{
     AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(
            new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey)
          );
    GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest tokenRequest = new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest();
    tokenRequest.setIdentityPoolId("us-east-1:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx");
    HashMap<String, String> providerTokens = new HashMap<String, String>();
    providerTokens.put(<developer provider name>,<some identifier backend>);
    String token = result.getToken();
        System.out.println(token);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

And it always fails in catch.

Comment: Apparently the null is genereated for lack of policies from my user.

Comment: I only have to attach the `AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities` policy to the user with whom I connect to Amazon and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have to attach the AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities policy to the user with whom I connect to Amazon and that's it.

[amazon Identity and Access Management console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4JSa.png)

Answer (score 0):

AccessDenied in this case points to that the policies on the IAM user/role do not allow the action you are trying to do. If you have any other questions please refer our [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) or feel free to post on our [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=173).